# How to set FragmentDialog size to wrap to ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, dialogfragment

I have RecyclerView and when I long click on one of items FragmentDialog appears with custom layout: |@ text|. The problem is Fragment Dialog does not wrap area only to those 2 elements but takes almost entire screen place. The problem still appears even when I set the layout to wrap the content. Here is the problem:
[image]

Here is RecyclerView custom_item XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <!-- Option Icon -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/recipe_dialog_option_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tint="@color/primary"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_email_48dp" />

    <!-- Text Option -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipe_dialog_option_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:text="Dodaj do Ulubionych" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is FragmentDialog layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and .class just in case:

```
package com.example.nazwamarki.myapplication.recipedialog;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;

import com.example.nazwamarki.myapplication.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecipeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private ArrayList<RecipeDialogItem> recipeDialogItems;
    private RecipeDialogAdapter recipeDialogAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        recipeDialogItems = new ArrayList<>();
        RecyclerView dialogRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(
                R.id.dialog_recycler_view);

        fillRecipeDialogArray(recipeDialogItems);

        recipeDialogAdapter = new RecipeDialogAdapter(getContext(), recipeDialogItems,
                R.layout.recipe_dialog_item);

        dialogRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        dialogRecyclerView.setAdapter(recipeDialogAdapter);
        dialogRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    }

    private void fillRecipeDialogArray(ArrayList<RecipeDialogItem> recipeDialogitem) {
        RecipeDialogItem dialogItem;

        String[] names = new String[] {"Account", "Star"};
        int[] icons = new int[] {R.drawable.ic_account_plus_48dp, R.drawable.ic_account_star_48dp};

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            dialogItem = new RecipeDialogItem();
            dialogItem.setRowIcon(icons[i]);
            dialogItem.setRowOption(names[i]);
            recipeDialogitem.add(dialogItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try overriding onMeasure of DialogFragment and passing your desired size to the super method?

Comment: I used http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/06/android-dialogfragment-listview.html toutorial. it's strange cause they make ListView (I RecyclerView) and they get desired effect. But how?

Comment: did you tried to change the recycler view height to wrap_content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `ListView` width to `DialogFragment` then do the following in `onStart()` of `DialogFragment`

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
  super.onStart();

  // safety check
  if (getDialog() == null)
    return;

  int dialogWidth = getArguments().getInt("width"); // specify a value here
  int dialogHeight = ... // specify a value here

  getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(dialogWidth, dialogHeight);

  // ... other stuff you want to do in your onStart() method
}
```

Best practice for [`Showing DialogFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#BasicDialog)

```
private void showDialog() {
    // DialogFragment.show() will take care of adding the fragment
    // in a transaction.  We also want to remove any currently showing
    // dialog, so make our own transaction and take care of that here.
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
    if (prev != null) {
        transaction.remove(prev);
    }
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    // Create and show the dialog.
    DialogFragment newFragment = RecipeDialogFragment.newInstance(width);
    newFragment.show(transaction, "dialog");
}
```

**RecipeDialogFragment**

```
    /**--Static factory method---
     * Create a new instance of RecipeDialogFragment, providing "width"
     * as arguments.
     */
    static RecipeDialogFragment newInstance(int width) {
        RecipeDialogFragment fragment = new RecipeDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle(1);
        args.putInt("width", width);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

Comment: Bad answer. You have to calculate height. So why wrap_content is?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove this line:

```
dialogRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

`RecyclerView` **don't know about wrap_content**. Same issue. See here: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399252/make-recyclerview-to-wrap-its-content-when-using-cardview-with-square-imageview).