# Make RecyclerView to wrap its content when using CardView with square ImageView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, layout-manager, android-cardview

I am trying to achieve following structure (image below). As you can see there are two sections with `RecyclerView`s and `CardView`s in it. These two sections are divided by two `TextView`s with `Button`s.

[image]

Each section should match screen width (minus indent between cards). Each `CardView` has square `ImageView` in it. So the height of `CardView` itself depend on screen width: `card_height = screen_width - indent_between_cards + space_for_card_text`. To achieve this behaviour I use simple `SquareImageView`, which looks like this:

```
public class SquaredImageView extends ImageView {

  public SquaredImageView(Context context) {
      super(context);
  }

  public SquaredImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
  }

  public SquaredImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
      super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
      int width = getMeasuredWidth();
      setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
  }
}
```

The CardView layout looks like this:

```
<CardView 
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:background="@color/snow"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Image -->
    <com.test.views.SquaredImageView
        android:id="@+id/card_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Content -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!-- Title -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/stone_dark"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <!-- Button -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/card_menu"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu" />    
    </LinearLayout>
</CardView>
```

It means, that `RecyclerView`'s adapter don't know the dimensions of `CardView` in advance.

As you probably know, `RecyclerView` has no system, which can measure its child-views, to make wrap its content correctly.

But unpredictable `SquareImageView` + fullscreen `RecyclerView` works fine in most of cases except the one described in this question.

- *So what's the problem? You should use your own `LayoutManager` or [`WrappableLayoutManager`](https://github.com/serso/android-linear-layout-manager) by [`@se-solovyev`](https://stackoverflow.com/u/720489) to solve your problem.*

The problem is in unpredictable `SquareImageView`. When `LayoutManager` tries to measure its child, it gets nothing. It means that `RecyclerView` displayed in fullscreen (as if `height` and `width` are set to `match_parent`).

So the question is: how to make `RecyclerView` with unpredictable `SquareImageView`s wrap its content correctly?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just use fixed dimensions for the ImageView (like 100x100dp)?